# SQL Search query error in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I am trying to build a search query. I got following error, It seems syntax error of sql.

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: select * from products
>   where styles = Abstract , Abstract and subject = ? )

Why this error occurred ?
How to figure it out ?

My code as follows

```
if (isset($request->search)) { 

    //GET ALL INPUT FROM THE REQUEST       
    $query_strings = $request->all();            

    //PULL OUT ANY EMPTY FIELD FROM THE REQUEST
    $filtered_array = array_filter($request->all());

    //remove the last item
    array_pop($filtered_array);

    //BUILD A QUERY 
    $sql = array();
    $values = array();
    $x = 1;
    foreach ( $filtered_array as $key =>$value ) {           
        if($x < count($filtered_array)){
            $sql[]=" $key = ? and ";
            $values[] =" $value , ";
          } else { 
            $sql[]=" $key = ? ";
            $values[] ="  $value  ";
          }
            $x++;
     }

     $fields = join(' ',  $sql);
     $v = join(' ',$values);

     dd( \DB::select("select * from products where {$fields} ", [$v]));

}
```

Comment: It's Laravel you're talking about and you're using none of it :( Also can you explain a bit more where you're getting an error and what error are you getting.

Answer (score 0):

When you're passing some values, you should add `?` placeholder:

```
\DB::select("select * from products where ?", [$value]));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a stretch and I doubt it will work as is on the first try. But I really suggest you try and make use of the Laravel's [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries).

This code assumes you're passing 'products' table column names as names of GET or POST parameters and values you want to query by as values. For example:

```
url.com?price=200&size=2
```

Where 'price' and 'size' are column names of 'products' table.

Code:

```
// Check if request has 'search' parameter
if($request->has('search')) { 
  // $filtered_array now has all parameters that were passed to the controller
  $filtered_array = $request->all();

  // Start a query on table 'products'. Laravel style (more: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries)
  $query = \DB::table('products');

  // For each parameter passed to the controller, we make "and where products.$key = $value" statement in the query
  foreach($filtered_array as $key => $value) {
    $query->where($key, '=', $value);
  }

  // Tell the query builder to get the results and save it to $results variable
  $results = $query->get();
}
```

This will undoubtedly cause a lot of errors as anyone can send anything as GET/POST parameters and query by that (which will throw SQL error that the column doesn't exist).

You should change the `$filtered_array = $request->all()` to:

```
$filtered_array = $request->only(['id', 'price', 'size']);
```

This way you will store only the parameters you specify in the ->only(array) in the $filtered_array and ignore all the others. So you should replace 'id', 'price' and 'size' with all the columns of the 'products' table you wish to query by.